# Symfony 3 - multiple login methods, how to set default?

Tags: php, symfony

So we've got multiple authentication methods for our site - SAML and normal form login. How do we set saml to be the default? Currently, when a user is not logged in and accesses the site, they're redirected to the form login page. The SAML bundle we are using is the hslavich OneLogin SAML bundle.

```
firewalls:
  app:
    pattern:    ^/
    anonymous: true
    saml:
      check_path: /saml_consume.php
      login_path: /saml/login
      user_factory: sonicwall_user_factory
      persist_user: true
      use_referer: true
    form_login:
      login_path: login
      check_path: login
      always_use_default_target_path: true
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to achieve what you want by overriding

```
class SamlFactory extends \Hslavich\OneloginSamlBundle\DependencyInjection\Security\Factory\SamlFactory
{
    /**
     * Defines the position at which the provider is called.
     * Possible values: pre_auth, form, http, and remember_me.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPosition()
    {
        return 'form';
    }
}
```

And registering this class in place of SamlFactory from the bundle

```
$extension->addSecurityListenerFactory(new SamlFactory());
```

By default it was set to `pre_auth`